# Limit Spring Webservice concurrent calls

Tags: java, spring, web-services, concurrency

I would like to optimize and reduce REST-API usage abuse for my service.

So, is there any "out of the box" way to limit the amount of concurrent calls to a webserivce on java spring?

for instance, if I have this method below

```
@RequestMapping(value="demo",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public synchronized @ResponseBody ObjectNode getDemo()
    {
        logger.info("started.. demo ");
        ObjectNode node = om.createObjectNode().put("test", true);
        logger.info("end.. demo");
        return node;
    }
```

i will be limiting this service to only 1 user at time. but, how  about limiting it to 4 or 10 concurrent users?

Thanks :)

Comment: have you found any solution? i'm having same issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is ***no*** out-of-box [rate limiting support](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13908) for Spring as of now.

However if you have / can use Google Guava then there is a support in form of `RateLimiter` class which has detailed explanation [here](https://dzone.com/articles/ratelimiter-discovering-google).

In case Google Gauva is not an option consider implementing rate limiter via [Token Bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) algorithm.

Sample implementation should have below components -

- A *bucket* to hold tokens (*preferable an in-memory cache*)
- A *servlet filter* to intercept the request (*preferably configure only those URL which are to be rate limited in `web.xml` and avoid `/*` pattern*)
- A *scheduled service* to replenish the bucket periodically

**Bucket** - In its simplest form a bucket can be created as a cache entry with key name as the URL and value as the available token(s) as shown in example below

> key = '/test/demo' value = 5
>   
> key = '/test/otherDemo' value = 10

*Preferably use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) to hold the token count to avoid any concurrent access issue*

**Filter** - Here simply try acquiring a token from bucket (*i.e. read the cache and look for positive value of token; decrement the token value by one for every request until zero*). 
Proceed with request only when token is acquired else block request with [HTTP status code 429](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#429)

**Scheduler** - A cron based scheduled service (*see Spring `@Scheduled`*) to reset the cache with maximum allowed request per unit of time.

Let me know in comments if you need more information.

Comment: Good approach, however, I was thinking to limit my service to use a fixed amount of concurrent calls (let's say 4). this is because, I'm not sure how long a call to this service could take. and the more concurrent calls, the slower the service.

Comment: In this case you can still use this approach as the scheduler will replenish the bucket to fixed number in every run (*4 in your case*). As an addition the maximum number of allowed call can be kept configurable (*in property file / database*)

Comment: no, i don't think what @Bond-JavaBond said is possible in this scenario.